# HttpListener return audio file so it plays on browser

Tags: c#, http, webserver, httplistener

I am using the [HttpListener](https://thecsharper.com/?p=409) class to create a very simple web server.

I am able to serve html, javascript, attachements probably everything to the browser. **The only thing I am having trouble is giving the browser a wav file so that it plays it.**

The file that I want to play in the browser is this one:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/81397375/a.wav

**Note how if you click on that link your browser starts playing the audio file instead of downloading it as an attachment. I want to do the same thing with the HttpListerner class!**

Anyways here is my code:

```
string pathToMyAudioFile = @"c:\a.wav";

// create web server
var web = new HttpListener();

// listen on port 8081 only on local connections for testing purposes
web.Prefixes.Add("http://localhost:8081/");

Console.WriteLine(@"Listening...");

web.Start();

// run web server forever
while (true)
{
    var context = web.GetContext();

    var requestUrl = context.Request.Url.LocalPath.Trim('/');

    // this command will stop the web server
    if (requestUrl == "Stop")
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = 200; // set response to ok
        context.Response.OutputStream.Close();
        break; 
    }
    else if (requestUrl == "DownloadAudio") // <--------- here is where I am interested
    {
        // we are ready to give audio file to browser
        using (var fs = new FileStream(pathToMyAudioFile , FileMode.Open))
        {
            context.Response.ContentLength64 = fs.Length;
            context.Response.SendChunked = true;
            //obj.Response.ContentType = System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet;
            context.Response.ContentType = "audio/wav";

            //obj.Response.AddHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fs.Name);
            context.Response.StatusCode = 206; // set to partial content

            byte[] buffer = new byte[64 * 1024];

            try
            {
                using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(context.Response.OutputStream))
                {
                    int read;
                    while ((read = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                    {

                        bw.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                        bw.Flush(); //seems to have no effect
                    }

                    bw.Close();
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                Console.Write("closded connection");
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = 404; // set response to not found
    }

    // close output stream
    context.Response.OutputStream.Close();
}

web.Stop();
```

Now when I go to `http://localhost:8081/DownloadAudio` I see this:

[image]

**But I am not able to play the file. Why?** What headers am I missing? I do not want to download the file as an attachment.

---

### Solution

I just found the solution. I was missing the `Content-Range` header. This how the response looks when making it agains a real web server IIS:

[image]

Note how it specifies the ranges it sends with the header:  `Content-Range: bytes 0-491515/491516`

So I just have to add the line

```
context.Response.Headers.Add("Content-Range", $"bytes 0-{fs.Length-1}/{fs.Length}");
```

To my code and now it works! If the audio file is very large I could do some math so I do not return everything at once.

Comment: When I click that link my browser downloads the wav file, not playing it.

Comment: why are you setting the status code to 206???

Comment: 206 is a partial content response. @Julian

Comment: I know that. The question is - why are you sending it, if your response is the full audio content? Note the documentation about status code 206 in the HTTP spec: https://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7233.html#status.206

Comment: That is the answer @JulianReschke. Thanks for the link that explains it better!